# Flutter UI breaks when "smallest width" is changed in developer options

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new into flutter programming. I have been working on a certain UI as shown below.

[image]

If I attempt to change the "smallest width" option in the developer options and set to some other value than the default, the whole UI breaks as shown.

[image]

[image]

I must add that the middle area which got completely broken was a stack widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SinglePlayerGameState>(
      builder: (context, gameState, child) => Expanded(
        flex: 48,
        child: Container(
          color: gameState.getGameColor(),
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: 45,
                    child: UNOcard(UNOcardData(CardTypes.BACK)),
                  ),
                  top: -30,
                  left: 90,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: 65,
                    child: UNOcard(UNOcardData(CardTypes.BACK)),
                  ),
                  top: 20,
                  left: 50,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: 180,
                    child: UNOcard(UNOcardData(CardTypes.BACK)),
                  ),
                  top: 100,
                  left: 65,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: 45,
                    child: UNOcard(UNOcardData(CardTypes.BACK)),
                  ),
                  top: 10,
                  right: 10,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: 65,
                    child: UNOcard(UNOcardData(CardTypes.BACK)),
                  ),
                  top: 120,
                  right: 50,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        color: Colors.black),
                    child: Text(
                      "${gameState.playingCards.length}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontFamily: 'Frijole',
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                  ),
                  top: 10,
                  left: 10,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: Center(
                        child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        gameState.nextTurn();
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.undoAlt,
                        size: 25,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                    height: 35,
                    width: 60,
                  ),
                  bottom: 10,
                  left: 10,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: DragTarget<UNOcardData>(
                    onWillAccept: (UNOcardData data) {
                      var res = isValidMove(
                          data, gameState.onGoingCards.last, gameState);
                      if(res){
                        print(res);
                        return true;
                      }else{
                        vibrate();
                         return false;
                      }
                    },
                    onAccept: (UNOcardData data) {
                      print(data);
                      performAction(data, gameState);
                    },
                    builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) =>
                        Transform.rotate(
                      angle: 0,
                      child: gameState.onGoingCards.last,
                    ),
                  ),
                  top: 60,
                  right: 100,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Like we use units like "vmin , vmax , vh " etc in html/css for responsive texts and sizes, what are the alternatives in flutter ? How do we responsive apps in flutter exactly ? I am not talking about scaling to other screen sizes, but to slightly different resolutions and logical pixel densities.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you can use `https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text` plugin for auto-sizing the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using margins from the edges with

```
Positioned(
  child: Transform.rotate(
    angle: 180,
    child: UNOcard(UNOcardData(CardTypes.BACK)),
  ),
  top: 100,
  left: 65,
),
```

This top means that it's going to position itself 100 units from the top. What you actually want is some percentage offset from the center. You can do it like this:

```
Positioned.fill(
  child: Align(
    // (0, 0) is the center, (1, 1) is right bottom, (-1, -1) is left top and so on
    alignment: Alignment(0.25, 0.25), 
    child: YOUR_WIDGET
  )
);
```

For more responsive UI you can get screen_sizes with [MediaQuery.of(context)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) or use a package like [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) to scale your UI according to a sample, like for example 1080x1920 screen.

Comment: arranging children from the center seems most appropriate.

Comment: Yes, this 0.25, 0.25 means that the widget will position itself in 1/4th of the distance from the center to the bottom right corner, it should be done for all of the cards, fancy way would be calculating with with sin and cosin for the whole list of widget, but manual way will work too and can be done faster.